# Using SignalR as Customer Service Representative

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, signalr

Hello everyone and thanks for the help in advance.  I need to develop a customer service chat application and am considering using SignalR as I have worked with it a little in the past.  I have two questions, first, is SignalR a viable technology for this type of application.  Second, if I understand the concepts correctly, each customer service engagement would require a separate room in order for each chat session to be unique and private.  Most of the chat examples I have seen require the user to enter a room name which is cumbersome to the user.  Also, since the responses will be auto-generated, I need to understand the best practices of logging and responding to the customer inquiry.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you think about the "group" concept in singalr? See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0#groups-in-signalr) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SignalR for this but I am not sure it would be the best technology.  You would need to keep track of the connected clients using either connection ID or groups and reply to each client like you would to a caller.  This is built-in with SignalR so that will make your implementation simpler and only the caller will see the reply.  SignalR also supports various security features like headers which will be a plus.  You should not need a chat room as this is just a feature of chat programs where rooms have topics and guests.

Keep in mind how many users you expect to have at any one time and how scalable your solution needs to be. In my experience with SignalR for ASP.NET (not Core), it worked great on one server but had many problems with scale out.

Depending on what you are trying to do, a commercial solution might be the best approach.  I know of a few companies that ended up going with a commercial solution after investigating building a chatbot inhouse.